# Export OBJ with materials crashes Blender on import

Tags: materials, export, import

I am having an issue with exporting obj files containing materials. I have created default materials in cycles with no changes other than diffuse color for each mesh in my scene, and I export to obj with materials. It is a basic scene, just a few different meshes with a single default material applied to each.

When I try to reimport the files into blender it freezes and can not import it. I am able to export the obj without the materials selection and everything works however in this case I need  separate material for each object created in Blender to be exported.

Anyone have an idea of what to look at to get the export to work properly?

Thanks

Comment: Solution I found was to export the .obj out with no materials. Import the obj into a brand new scene and recreate all the materials. I am not sure what caused this there seems to be no difference in the materials I created before.

Comment: Why are you using OBJ format to export and import stuff back to Blender? Why don't you use natve Blender's format if it's only Blender you are working with?

Comment: I was reopening the obj file in blender just to make sure that they exported correctly and everything was good to go. I had this issues come up on a couple obj exports. I also found that deleting every material out of the scene, save the file, reopen it so that is it clean with no materials, then make all new materials also allowed me to get obj exports that didn't crash.

Answer (score 1):

Export the .obj out with no materials (unselect write materials on export). Import the obj into a brand new scene and recreate all the materials.